# Static Google Earth Map for use in GWT

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, gwt, google-earth-plugin

I am currently working on a project that uses a [Google Earth API library that is wrapped in java](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-earth-3/) so that one may use this library in the Google Web Toolkit to make a Google Earth Widget. I was wondering if you could get a static implementation or static instance of the Google Earth map so that the user can view this page offline. I would really appreciate if anyone who has knowledge about this could get back to me as soon as possible. If it is possible to do so,  I hope to work with the developer of the library to include this implementation in a future release of the library. I know that in the desktop application, one can cache the map for offline use. If it is not possible to obtain a static map then I would like to know if you could cache the map on the user's computer for offline use.

Thanks,

MPH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found a viable solution. I am currently using a gwt-wrapped version of openlayers with an open street map server. This should allow for me to be able to take my project offline if I serve the image tiles from OSM locally on my own machine. That way I can just call the tiles locally and just update the server when needed. The only drawback is the server can become quite large in memory and it only adjusts the map to what you have downloaded to the server :/

Answer (score 1):

There's the [Static Maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps) API. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "view page offline" in this context, though.

Comment: The page will be called by a local server on the same network. Basically offline means that there will be no internet connection, which is necessary for the Widget to load up on the page.

Comment: I would like the page to load a local version of the Google Earth map.